# Trouble with access role when inserting shared calendar to my list from google calendar API using service account

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar, google-calendar-api

Initial situation:

- In one of my python app, we use a service account to call Google
  Calendar API.
- User can share their calendars with my service account via its proper email address
- User also put shared calendars ids on my system
- On my system, i have a proper calendars ids with proper permissions from shared calendars with my service account
- I am trying to accept shared calendars with me by calendar id via Calendar Api with this endpoint [https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert?authuser=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9fJl.png)
- I am not using G-Suite for service account

Current issue:

- When i accept shared calendar via API it returns the correct [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9fJl.png) with external calendar data but actually not inserting calendar to my list. I think it's through access role returned in response `accessRole=reader` and looks like i don't have writer permissions from the service account.

I am using `oauth2client` and `googleapiclient` libraries to authenticate my service account.

Comment: You shouldn't require that users share their calendars with a service account.  You should be using Oauth2 to authenticate to a users calendar.    Service accounts are for preapproving access to an account you the developer own.   Calendar list is populated by you.  If you want something in that you need to do calendarlist.insert its not going to be inserted in automatically

Comment: So I assume you're calling [CalendarList: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) with your service account after the calendar has been shared by the user through the UI? How do you know the calendar is not getting inserted? Are you using `CalendarList: list` or `CalendarList: get` to check that?

Comment: @lamblichus. `So I assume you're calling CalendarList: insert with your service account after the calendar has been shared by the user through the UI?` - correct. When i am inserting shared calendar via API to my list i want to see that it was added in UI too, not only check through `CalendarList: list`. So i was testing only through the UI.

Comment: DaImTo. `If you want something in that you need to do calendarlist.insert its not going to be inserted in automatically` - Yeah, i am doing inserting on BE after user saves his calendar id on my system.

Comment: A service account is not you. If you're using a service account by itself (not using impersonation), the calendars are not getting added to a regular user's list, but to the service account's list. And this list cannot be viewed via UI, only through the API. So my guess is that the calendars are actually added to the service account, but you are not looking at the right place. Can you check whether `CalendarList: list` returns the list of calendars? Also, why are you using a service account? Do you want the calendars to be shared with your regular account instead?

Comment: I will check if it exists in my service account list. I am using a service account to avoid OAuth2 on client side. What i need - it's to have a possibility to work with shared calendars without OAuth2. Is it possible to display shared calendars in my list through UI?

Comment: In this case, you could grant domain-wide authority to your service account so that it can impersonate a regular account and access the API on this account's behalf, without user interaction. But anyway, why not sharing the calendars directly with a regular account. I'm still not sure I understand why you're using a service account, since the sharing process would still be done by regular users, which would require user interaction during OAuth, is that correct?

Comment: When a Calendar is shared with a regular account, this account doesn't need to call `CalendarList: insert` in order to have this calendar in their list AFAIK. Only service accounts require that. Therefore, I don't understand how using a service account would allow for less user interaction in this specific case. Could you please clarify your situation and your current purposes?

Comment: But `domain-wide authority` - as i know working only for users within specific domain. In my case it will be just different users which not belong to specific domain.

Comment: For what i need that? In my python app, i need to have access to calendars that users shared with me to do some actions with them. Users don't need to do something with their shared calendar in my application, my application should have such a possibility. For example, my application wants to add some event to the specific user's calendar. Iamblichus

Comment: I mentioned `domain-wide authority` because you asked `Is it possible to display shared calendars in my list through UI?`. The thing is, you cannot look at the list of calendars shared with a service account through UI, because **the service account does not have a Calendar UI**. If you don't need to access them via UI, then I'd suggest you to call `CalendarList: list` in order to check whether the Calendars have actually been added to the service account. After all, that's what you wanted to do, right?

Comment: Understood. I would ask you for the last one. Will it work as i want when using OAuth2?

Comment: By `work as i want` do you mean that the Calendars will be display on a Calendar UI? And by `using OAuth2` I assume that you mean using a regular account instead of a service account, right? If both answers are affirmative, then yes, the Calendars will be displayed on the regular account's UI if you share the calendars with this regular account. Also, please be aware that auth with a service account is also OAuth2 (see [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)). Finally, does this answer your original question? In that case, I'd consider posting an answer.

Comment: So that's almost clear for now but i am a bit confused about regular account. Can you shortly explain about regular account and difference between regular and service account? What do you mean exact under regular account?

Comment: A regular account is an account that is connected to a specific user. If you have a Google account, with which you access Gmail UI, Drive UI, etc., that's a regular account. You can use this account to access the Google APIs. By contrast, a service account is not connected to a specific user, but to an application, and it doesn't have UI (you cannot access Gmail UI, for example). I hope this is clear for you?

Comment: Yep. I understand what you are talking about. So i will try to set up my calendar API with OAuth2 under regular account and let you know if it's working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You're sharing some Calendars with a service account, and you cannot see those Calendars on the UI.

#### Answer:

A service account, unlike regular accounts, **does not have a Calendar UI**. If you're looking for these Calendars on your regular account's UI, you won't find them, since the service account is not you. But this doesn't mean these have not been shared. The only way to see which Calendars are in the service account's CalendarList is to list them through the API (see [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)).

With that said, if your purpose is to be able to see the shared Calendars on the UI, you have to share them with a regular (that is, a user) account, either [via API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing#sharing_calendars) or directly [through the UI](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en#).

#### Further reading:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)